# C Segmentation fault when spitting a string

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

First of all sorry if I this is a basic (or stupid) question, I am coming from Python and I am quite new in C (still studying it).

I have a short script to split a string into sub-strings,
for example: "this is my -string" into "this","is","my","-string".

After that I want to select the substring that starts with the char: '-', and save in a variable calls "subline":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CHAR 9999

int main ()
{

  char line[] ="this is my -string";
  char *p;
  char subline[MAX_CHAR];


  printf ("Split string in tokens:\n");

  p = strtok (line," ");

  while (p != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n", p);
    p = strtok (NULL, " ,");

    if ((strncmp(p, "-", 1) == 0)){ 
      memcpy(subline, ++p, strlen(p)+1);
      printf ("subline: %s\n", subline);

    }


  }
  printf ("\nData:\n");
  printf ("subline is: %s\n", subline);
  return 0;
}
```

Everything runs fine inside the while loop, where I can even print the variable "subline", but outside the while loop I get a segmentation fault, here is the output:

```
root@debian:/home/user/Desktop/splits# ./split
Split string in tokens:
this
is
my
subline: string
string
Segmentation fault
```

I tried to figure out and solved it using malloc(sizeof(*subline)); but always the same segmentation fault outside the while loop.

Anyone has any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, The NULL says to pick up where the last `strtok()` call left off.  That's a very bizarre behavior by today's standards, but there you have it.

Comment: `memcpy(subline, ++p, strlen(p)+1);` is a *horrible* idea. There is no sequence-point between evaluations of arguments for a function.

Comment: Just a suggestion:  I would replace `if ( strncmp( p, "-", 1) == 0 )` with `if ( *p == '-' )`.  It is a change from a string comparison to a character comparison.  Take care with the single and double quotes.  And as my answer suggests, do check p before using it.

Comment: `p = strtok (NULL, " ,");` move to loop-end

Comment: @EOF I know it's a horrible idea, but I couldnt figure out other way to do the same, would be nice if you could share some better idea ;)

Comment: "... I couldnt figure out other way to do the same ..." What "same"? Invoking _undefined behaviour_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `p` becomes null, you still pass it to `strcncmp()`.  Don't do that -- add another check instead.

NULL is returned by `strtok` when there are no more matches, which the code detects in the while-loop, but before the loop logic will catch it, the `strncmp()` method is called with the NULL pointer.

Comment: @ash, Thanks for the edit.  That does help paint the whole picture.

Comment: You're welcome.  I also agree with the comment the NULL to strtok is add (or just outdated), but how old is that thing?  :).  Not a function I would recommend to most devs these days!

Comment: It's like recommending some ancient tool to someone who fixes up antique cars.  (Probably) like you, I'd recommend starting fresh with new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

this is the main error:

the function strtok() is being called a second time, before the first string pointer has been processed

this line:

```
memcpy(subline, ++p, strlen(p)+1);
```

(remembering that 'p' is a pointer to the first character of the string, and pre-increment of that pointer inside the memcpy() function is a very bad idea due to certain 'side effects'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// wrap numerics in parens to avoid certain 'text replacement' errors
#define MAX_CHAR (9999)

int main ( void )
{

  char line[] ="this is my -string";
  char *p;
  char subline[MAX_CHAR] = {'\0'};  // assure the string will be properly terminated


  printf ("Split string in tokens:\n");

  p = strtok (line," "); // p now points to first token (or contains NULL

  while (p)   // will continue to loop while p not equal to NULL, where NULL is the same as 'false'
  {
      printf ("%s\n", p);

      // don't need all this power function call
      // if ((strncmp(p, "-", 1) == 0))
      if( '-' == p[0] )
      {
          p++; // step past the '-'
          memcpy(subline, p, strlen(p)); // remember, subline is init. to all '\0'
          printf ("subline: %s\n", subline);
      }

      p = strtok (NULL, " ,"); // p now points to next token (or contains NULL)
  } // end while

  printf ("\nData:\n");
  printf ("subline is: %s\n", subline);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wonder why the ',' in the strtok second parameter as there is no ',' to search for in the input string.